# Grafana is not able to get Prometheus metrics although Prometheus Datasource is validated successfully

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am trying to configure Grafana to visulaize metrics collected by Prometheus.
My Prometheus Datasource is validated successfully. But when I am trying to create dashboard then it's showing error saying `"can not read property 'result' of undefined"`

I am adding screenshots.
[image: Following image shows datasouces validated successfully]

[image: Second image shows waht error I am getting]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you are pointing towards the node exporter endpoint and not Prometheus Server. The default Prometheus Server endpoint is 9090. Try change your source to http://192.168.33.22:9090

Grafana doesn't query Node Exporter directly, it queries Prometheus Server which gathers the time series statistics.

Comment: Thank you @dcos. Finally able to access proemtheus metrics in grafan with your valuable help.

Comment: But i had given the PRometheus url in the data source, Still not getting data, Any idea

Comment: Did you change access type from proxy to direct? did you installed the node_exporter on all k8s nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the guide below to fix the issue!

This will work as long as you have both your Grafana and Prometheus running as a docker images so before you begin please  run the command below to be sure that both prom and Grafana images are up

```
docker ps
```

To connect the prometheus to GRAFANA, you will need to get the prometheus server IP address that is running as a docker image from host.

Use this command on your terminal to display all the container IDs:

```
docker ps -a
```

You will see your prometheus server container ID displayed for example "faca0c893603". Please copy the ID and run the command below on your terminal to see the IP address of your Prometheus server:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' faca0c893603
```

Note : (faca0c893603 is the ContainerID of the prom/prometheus server)

When you run the command it will display the IP address(172.17.0.3) of the Prometheus container which needs to be mapped with the port of the prometheus server on Grafana.

On data source on Grafana, put this on the URL http://172.17.0.3:9090 and try to save and test.

Comment: This solved my problem, and probably also the original question.

Comment: I'm glad It was helpful
Please kindly use the up arrow to rate the solution. it might be useful to someone esle